# Definition of step function : does intervals has to be finite?

Tags: real-analysis

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function#Definition_and_first_consequences), the define a step function as $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\mathbb 1_{A_i}$$
where $\mathbb 1_{A_i}$ are characteristic function and $A_i$ are disjoints interval. But they don't mention if $A_i$ has to be finite or not. In my memory, step function should be Riemann integrable and thus $A_i$ has to be finite, but since it's nowhere mention on wikipedia, I have a doubt. What do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

No, the intervals don't need to be finite in order for the function to be a step function.

Also, the intervals don't need to be finite in order for the function to be Riemann integrable. The function $f(x)=1_{[0,\infty)}$ is a Riemann integrable function.

Comment: As far as I know, Riemann integrable function has sense on interval of the form $[a,b]$. An integrale of $\boldsymbol 1_{[0,\infty )}$ is rather an improper integral, no ? And since the improper integral is infinite, it's not Riemann integrable... is it ?

Comment: @user659895 Sure, but $1_{[0,\infty)}$ is integrable on any finite subinterval on which it is defined.